# #define array index not working

Tags: c++, arrays, macros

I'm trying to #define a constant at the top of the header file and use that value as the index size of my arrays. I'm getting the following error:

> Error C2059: syntax error : ']'

I'm curious as to why?

```
#define MAX_TEAMS = 20;

class Program
{
  public:

  int atk_val[MAX_TEAMS]; // Error!
  int atk_val[20]; // Works!
}
```

Comment: `static const int MAX_TEAMS = 20;` instead of `#define`

Comment: please note that you should better use a `static const` as Captiain Obvlious pointed out, or even better use standard containers instead of plain arrays

Comment: and btw you are defining the size of the array and not its index. (yes sometimes I like hairsplitting). If your program has no bugs, the index should never reach this value ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Replace `#define MAX_TEAMS = 20;` with

```
#define MAX_TEAMS 20
```

In current form the code `int atk_val[MAX_TEAMS];` will be expanded to

```
int atk_val[= 20;];
//          ^   ^
```

And thus the error message seen by you.

Always remember that MACROs are **not** variables.

Answer (score 1):

When you define the symbol in this way:

```
#define MAX_TEAMS = 20;
```

you define `MAX_TEAMS` to be replaced with `= 20;`

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
 #define MAX_TEAMS = 20;
```

to

```
#define MAX_TEAMS  20
```

`#define` does a string substitution.

Comment: Please see the comment above - it is a better solution to mine in the C++ world.